# I have a linked table which is linked to a .txt file in my directory itself

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a linked table which is linked to a .txt file in my directory itself. Now I need to create a command button in a Form which helps me to relink the .txt file whenever I require, using VBA code.

Can anyone please help me on this.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XbHv.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to. The file/data will be read "as is" whenever you open the table.

If you wish to update the text file, just replace it with the new file.

Comment: Hi Gustav. Thanks for the reply. But i need to refresh my linked table anyway. SO i found this code helpful.                                                         Private Sub Command3_Click()


    Dim b As Boolean
    b = RefreshLinkedTables()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. But i need to refresh my linked table anyway. So i found this code helpful. 
                                                        Private Sub Command3_Click()

```
Dim b As Boolean
b = RefreshLinkedTables()                                                                        End Sub  
                                                                                                 Function RefreshLinkedTables() As Boolean
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tb As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Set db = CurrentDb

For Each tb In db.TableDefs
    ' Skip system files.
    If (Mid(tb.Name, 1, 4) <> "MSys" And Mid(tb.Name, 1, 4) <> "~TMP") Then
        Debug.Print tb.Name
        Debug.Print tb.Connect
        'If (Mid(tb.Connect, 1, 5) = "ODBC;") Then

            If (tb.Name = "P60DZ30") Then
                tb.RefreshLink
                Debug.Print "Refreshing fields data"
                tb.Fields.Refresh

            End If
        'End If
        Debug.Print "=== === ==="
    End If
    db.TableDefs.Refresh
Next

Set db = Nothing

RefreshLinkedTables = True
Exit Function
```

End Function